# C fopen creating file in my user directory instead of desktop Mac

Tags: c, macos, file

I am messing around with reading and writing to files in C. I coded a program, which is saved on my desktop. I then compiled it using the terminal, also on the desktop. But when I ran the program, it said that everything was working, but the file was nowhere to be found. I used the spotlight search, and it said that my file was located in my `/Users/johndoe` directory. Here is the code. Thanks in advance for helping.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    FILE* fp1 = fopen("boop.txt", "a");
    fputs("Hello World\n", fp1);
    fclose(fp1);
    FILE* fp2 = fopen("boop.txt", "r");
    char* output = (char *) malloc(20);
    fgets(output, 20, fp2);
    printf("%s", output);
    fflush(stdout);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `"boop.txt"` does not begin with `/`, so it is a relative path and it opens relative to the working directory of the process when it executes.

Comment: @WilliamPursell so how can I fix this. I tried changing the name to ```/boop.txt``` and it doesn't work

Comment: What is there to fix?  If you want the file to open in the Desktop, use `"/path/to/Deskto/boop.txt"`, or run the program from the desktop.  eg, `cd /path/to/desktop; /path/to/executable`

Comment: How are you running the program?  Are you invoking it from a shell?

Comment: @WilliamPursell no I'm opening the executable

Comment: What do you mean by "opening the executable"?  I get the impression you are clicking on things in a windowing environment.  The purpose of windowing environments is to obfuscate everything and make it confusing.  (I suppose there are other reasons for them as well.)  So the working directory of the executing process will be obscured.  You could implement a webserver in the program and open  a tcp connection to it and have it report its working directory.  That would probably be less work that trying to figure out what your environment is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean when you say the terminal is "also on the desktop"?  I suspect you mean that the icon the execute the terminal is on the desktop, but the shell that is running inside the terminal has a working directory of $HOME.  When you run the program from the shell, type `pwd` to see the directory it is running in.  That is the directory in which the files will be created.

Comment: the pwd of the terminal I compiled the program in is ```/Users/johndoe/Desktop```

Comment: It doesn't matter where the executable sits. What matters is the working directory when the program runs.

Comment: How can I change it to the directory which the executable sits without hard-coding the path?

Comment: It depends on how you are running it.  If you are invoking it from a shell, you would cd to the desired directory before running the program.  If you are running it by clicking on something in a windowing environment, your guess is as good as mine.

Comment: Thanks William Pursell